# Disable down overscroll in ListView

Tags: android, listview, listeners, overscroll

I want to dissable down overscrolling in ListView and override onOverScrolled method. Also it will be perfect if I can detect when user try to top overscoll when start slide in his top state ( i mean he have a a first element on the top of listview) because overscroll triggers even if you swipe up and obtains top record.